# How to capture the headers of a 401 response or request with js o react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-headers, sip, jssip

How to capture the headers of a 401 response or request?
The server is returning this 401 to me since it needs a summary authentication, I need to create a hash to send it to the server from the MD5 algorithm, and I need to get the nonce from the 401 response to be able to calculate the MD5 algorithm, any ideas on how extract the headers the WWW-Authenticate nonce ? any ideas ?

I am using the JsSip.js library
work with react js or js

I leave the answer in an image that should censor some things

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58w45.png)

Comment: You should give a password to jssip configuration? Then, it will authenticate automatically. Have you tried?

Comment: yes I have tried but the server returns 401 indicating that it must be authenticated

Comment: Authentification should be automatic. The configuration for jssip is probably incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the token from the header you should use Axios interceptors to and access it via req.headers,the proper header for a token is headers.authorisation:'Bearer tokenValue', [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)

Comment: It seems to be an answer for an http message. But the question is on a sip message.

Comment: yeas I thought this was http , for sip It authenticates automatically , check on your configuration and see if everything checks

Answer (score 0):

the same thing happens to me, I show you the configuration that I am using, can you tell me please if any information is missing? Since the 401 is not being answered automatically.

My code is:

var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('wss://my.server.com/webrtc/')

```
var configuration = {
  sockets: [socket],
  uri: 'sip:TestUser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5060',
  password: 'xxxxxxx',
  //contact_uri: 'sip:TestUser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx',
}

var ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration)

ua.start()
```

Thank you for your answer.